# Errno 70: Stale NFS file handle error when loading ChromaDB Client

Tags: nfs, langchain, chromadb

I'm trying to build a knowledge chatbot that uses RAG to retrieve document knowledge. I'm opting to use chromadb for my vectorstore, but I'm having difficulty instantiating a ChromaDB client because of a Stale NFS file handle error. I've not seen any of the same errors online, and could use some help - I'm a beginner programmer!

Here's what I try to run:

```
import chromadb
chroma_client = chromadb.Client()
```

Running the above results in the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/dkwik/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Coding/knowledge-chatbot/knowledge-chatbot/django_chatbot/chatbot/doc_loader/doc_loader_chromadb.ipynb Cell 2 line 1
----> 1 chroma_client = chromadb.Client()

File ~/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Coding/knowledge-chatbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/__init__.py:188, in Client(settings, tenant, database)
    175 def Client(
    176     settings: Settings = __settings,
    177     tenant: str = DEFAULT_TENANT,
    178     database: str = DEFAULT_DATABASE,
    179 ) -> ClientAPI:
    180     """
    181     Return a running chroma.API instance
    182 
   (...)
    185 
    186     """
--> 188     return ClientCreator(tenant=tenant, database=database, settings=settings)

File ~/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Coding/knowledge-chatbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py:138, in Client.__init__(self, tenant, database, settings)
    132 def __init__(
    133     self,
    134     tenant: str = DEFAULT_TENANT,
    135     database: str = DEFAULT_DATABASE,
    136     settings: Settings = Settings(),
...
File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:982, in get_code(self, fullname)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1040, in get_data(self, path)

OSError: [Errno 70] Stale NFS file handle
```